# Eventhandler for TwinColSelect component in Vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin7

How to attach the select listener on TwinColSelect components selected list (Right hand side) ? ValueChange event gives all the selected items but I want to attach the listeners on individual item level where want to show furhter data based on selection.

for example: Say I have country values. It will get displayed on left hand side of twinColSelect component and I can add them to selected list. after adding then I want to show states of those country in some onther component say List. to populate list I need to know which country user clicked from selected list.

How to achieve this? How to get the selectItemListener on selected part (right hand side component)

Here is some code: PS- code is pulled from vaadin demo site:

```
sample = new TwinColSelect();
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
sample.addItem(i);
sample.setItemCaption(i, "Option " + i);
}
sample.setRows(6);
sample.setNullSelectionAllowed(true);
sample.setMultiSelect(true);
sample.setImmediate(true);
sample.setLeftColumnCaption("Available options");
sample.setRightColumnCaption("Selected options");
...

sample.addValueChangeListener(e -> Notification.show("Value changed:",
String.valueOf(e.getProperty().getValue()),
Type.TRAY_NOTIFICATION));
```

Here is the snapshot: [image]

If you see the snapshot, there are three items in selected options.  the listener `sample.addValueChangeListener(e -> Notification.show("Value changed:",
    String.valueOf(e.getProperty().getValue()),
    Type.TRAY_NOTIFICATION));`

returns collection of all selected options but there is no way to add event to selected option (right hand side) area.

I want to show another list when user clicks on these selected options. for example if user clicks on option 3 as shown in snapshot, I want to show option 3 related data.like wise for option 0 and option 2.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you show us some code that you develop?

Comment: added the code. code is pulled from vaadin demo site: http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/data-input/multiple-value/list-builder